# How to display GPX track names (and or descriptions) in a clickable popup when using the Leaflet.TimeDimension plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

my coding knowledge is next to nothing, but I am having heaps of fun trying to learn.

I have been amending the code from Leaflet TimeDimension example 9: http://apps.socib.es/Leaflet.TimeDimension/examples/example9.html to try and show animal movement through time on a map created in Leaflet.

I have a self written GPX file and KML track containing the individual animal's lats and longs through time. I have also added the time dimension so that I can play the time slider and my custom icons move across the map as I would like. However, I have now hit a wall.

I would like to be able to click on a marker (at any stage during the time sliders duration [marker position moves]) and bring up information about that marker in a popup. This would be easy if there were actual markers (marker.bindPopup()) but the markers are created from a track in a GPX file:

*example of an animals track in the GPX file*:

```
...
<trk><name>THE DESCRIPTION I WANT TO DISPLAY IN A POPUP</name><number>2</number><trkseg>
    <trkpt lat="-40" lon="120"><ele>2</ele><time>2018-01-06T10:09:57Z</time></trkpt>
    <trkpt lat="-41" lon="122"><ele>2</ele><time>2018-01-21T16:45:57Z</time></trkpt>
</trkseg></trk>
...
```

and I do not know how to call the name or the description of one of these tracks and bind the information in a popup (there are multiple sets of tracks [each with a unique name and description] in the single GPX file).

There are two main solutions I have been looking into (that I think might be possible) but can't quite get either to work.

1. use get_name() from the GPX.js script: https://github.com/mpetazzoni/leaflet-gpx

It says:

> If you want to display additional information about the GPX track, you can do so in the 'loaded' event handler, calling one of the following methods on the GPX object e.target:
>
> get_name(): returns the name of the GPX track

Here is the demo code: https://git.nxfifteen.rocks/rocks/core/raw/056ddab410a40496a917cb150be8d92f4cc205cf/map.php but this code is well beyond my understanding and I haven't been able to figure out how to make it work

I have tried:

```
function onClick(e) {
alert(this.get_name());
}
```

but it doesn't work (not sure if its heading in the right direction or not).

2. Somehow in the customLayer make the bindPopup link to the name of the GPX track

Here is the section of code in my .js file that calls and loads the GPX and KML layer:

```
var customLayer = L.geoJson(null, {
pointToLayer: function (feature, latLng) {
    if (feature.properties.hasOwnProperty('last')) {
        return new L.Marker(latLng, {
            icon: icon
        }).bindPopup ("yo");
    }
    return L.circleMarker(latLng).bindPopup ("hey");
}
});

var gpxLayer = omnivore.gpx('data/data.gpx', null, customLayer).on('ready', function(e) {
map.fitBounds(gpxLayer.getBounds(), {
    paddingTopLeft: [160, 160],
    paddingBottomRight: [100, 100]
});
});

var gpxTimeLayer = L.timeDimension.layer.geoJson(gpxLayer, {
updateTimeDimension: true,
addlastPoint: true,
waitForReady: true
});

var kmlLayer = omnivore.kml('data/data.kml');
var kmlTimeLayer = L.timeDimension.layer.geoJson(kmlLayer, {
updateTimeDimension: true,
addlastPoint: true,
waitForReady: true
});

gpxTimeLayer.addTo(map);
```

In the variable: customLayer that is linked to the GPX track using omnivore, I can add a clickable popup that says "yo" to every animals marker. I can pause the time slider at any point and when I click a marker "yo" popus up (almost what I need).

I was wondering if there is some way to, instead of it saying "yo", tell it to return the name of the track that has been clicked, so that each marker will display its respective name (the name will contain the description I want it to show).

Sorry this is such a long winded question, and thank you in advance for any solutions, tip or pointers on whether my attempts just need a bit of tweaking, or if there is a different better solution out there.

Comment: Can you add all your markers using the GPX.js method (the one at the very end of the README that adds custom markers), use get_name() to add the text to the popup as you go along, and then add the timeDimension layer after?

Comment: Not sure if the timeDimension layer will work using this method, but I will definitely give it a go. Thank you